# Changing Microsoft Sharepoint fieldvalues for files with C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm trying to change the field values for files stored in a Sharepoint List programmatically, but it seems i can't access these. There have been some helpful ideas and they look very promising, but it seems not to work at all. Here my code so far:

```
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(@"https://.........de");

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@"https://............de/software/ap_ck/Dokumenten%20Management%20System/100_001_000_1.txt");

            ListItem lstitem = file.ListItemAllFields;
            context.Load(lstitem);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            lstitem["Mandant"] = "Mercedes";
            lstitem.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Is there maybe something wrong with the code itself?

Comment: Did it throw any specific errors, or is it just not doing the expected action?

Comment: Not specifically within the application itself, but while setting a break point at ListItem lstitem = file.ListItemAllFields; i recieve a lot of exceptions for the variable of the type File. Those are "PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedExceptions"... I'm guessing that my C# code cannot access the Sharepoint library, but what's strange is that i can upload files to the library while using "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect()", i just can't access them again with the code provided here.

Comment: Is it even possible to remote-access Sharepoint this way? I mean uploading files works just fine.

Comment: Not sure. You might have better luck posting on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ instead, as they probably have a better knowledge of sharepoint

Comment: You are using the client object model, which doesn't load the properties unless you specify them with a call to `Load`. That's the reason of the PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedExceptions. So no, there seems nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Line two GetFileByServerRelativeUrl method, it needs the file relative url, please check the working demo below:

```
 ClientContext context = new ClientContext(@"http://sp2016/sites/test");

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@"/sites/test/Documents1/folder2/test.txt");

    ListItem lstitem = file.ListItemAllFields;
    context.Load(lstitem);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    lstitem["Title"] = "Mercedes";
    lstitem.Update();
    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

[image]

Comment: This works flawlessly. I know thanking people is depreciated here, but i want to let you know that you saved my future in that line of work, as this is part of my final project of my apprenticeship as a software developer. So again, thank you so much.